# jQuery UI Autocomplete on KeyPress write value

Tags: jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am trying to implement jQuery UI Autocomplete the way like
when I have a list "alpha","beta","gamma" then type "a" into the input field
and only get "alpha" as proposal I want to hit enter and "alpha" shall be
the new value of the input field instead of selecting "alpha" by mouse click.
Is this possible?

```
$.ajax({ 
    url   : 'myAjax.php', 
    type  : 'POST',
    data  : { param: getData },
    dataType : 'json',
    success  : function(data) {                  

        $("#myField").autocomplete({

            minLength: 0,                       
            source: data,
            focus: function( event, ui ) {                      
                $(this).val(ui.item.key);
                return false;
            },
            select: function( event, ui ) {

                $("#myField").val(ui.item.value);

                return false;
            }        
        });            
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add

```
autoFocus: true
```

this will make it focus on the first element that you get 
and when you press enter it will automatically put the label in the field by using

```
$("#myField").val(ui.item.label);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, you have to put more parameter on your autocomplete method

```
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
 source: function( request, response ) {
     var matcher = new RegExp( "^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex( request.term ), "i" );
     response( $.grep( data, function( item ){
         return matcher.test( item.label );
     }) );
},
minLength: 1,
select: function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#tags").val(ui.item.label);
    $("#selected-tag").val(ui.item.label);
    window.location.href = ui.item.value;
}
,
focus: function(event, ui) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $("#tags").val(ui.item.label);
}
});
```

see this exemple [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/gMrpcoKRGFVKFVtn9gis?p=preview)

Comment: It is not working: Im typing 'a' and 'Apple' is proposed for selection but when I press enter the input field does not have the value 'Apple' but still 'a'.

Comment: I mean I do not intend to use the mouse. I want to enter a keyword and if result is one just press enter to see the result in the input field.